# Access Point ( AIR-SAP2602E-N-K9 ) or Router ( DLink DIR-615 )?

Tags: wireless-networking

I don't know the difference between access point and router. We are going to setup network for 100 users in our organization.

Please help in taking this decision.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a router on your network (i assume you do if you have 100 users), the access point is fine to provide wifi IMHO...

Comment: pataluc **Thank you** for reply.. There is a marginal difference in cost.Therefore I would like to know the importance of having access point in network.

Comment: see related question: http://superuser.com/questions/42524/difference-between-wifi-router-and-access-point?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Access point is simply a hotspot for wireless devices such as laptops & mobiles

Wireless devices also servers as router (if it connects internet or other network) as it connects two different networks.

Comment: Ashish **Thank you** for the information .. There is a marginal difference in cost.Therefore I would like to know the importance of having access point in network than having just a wireless router which will serve wireless devices.