# We have 2 computers, one wireless only (new, windows 10) and one wired only (old, vista) and we want hook both to our dsl.

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wired

We are a historical society with very old volunteers that want to use the old (vista) machine they are comfortable with. It's hooked to our DSL router just to read email and do some basic data entry. Our new windows 10 machine only has wireless, no hookup for DSL in the back. Can we use our router (4 open plugs) to A) hook our old machine up and B) use one of the plugs to put a wireless router on to use the newer machine so that both can be on the internet at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! That's what those plugs are there for.

Instead of a wireless router, you probably want something like an Access Point instead, see [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/42524/difference-between-wifi-router-and-access-point).

Basically you will need something to extend your network. Another router will do that, but it will create a second sub-network and then you'll run into funky double-NAT issues.

A better solution is going for a [Wireless Access Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_access_point). It will allow wireless devices to connect your current network without running into the issues a second router would introduce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are on the right track.  You need a wireless router.  But instead of connecting the old computer to the old DSL box, you will probably want to connect it to the wireless router also.  Most wireless routers also include 4 wired ports.  The advantage to having both computers on the same router is they could then possible share data or share a printer.